# Preventing spam website to open tabs, popup and url automatically

Tags: google-chrome, spam-prevention

If you visit https://1337x.to or https://ilcorsaronero.info/cat/1 with Chrome (v. 62.0.3202.94) some pages will be automatically be opened even if the popup setting should prevent this from happening.

Any workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best browser add-on I've ever used is [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=ar) nothing can escape from it.
I advice you to use it.

**EDIT:**
**The English version of the add-on page is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en).**

Comment: Your link takes to the Arabic page :P Otherwise, I absolutely agree, best ad blocker ever, single click disable for a particular site

Comment: Anytime @Revious

Answer (score 1):

It's JAVA Script that's causing those new windows even when Pop Ups are disabled.
In Chrome, you type **About:settings** in the address bar

Open **Advanced Settings**

Then **Content Settings**

```
 Next **Java Script**
```

Then enter line by line, base URL's prohibited from executing JScript.

There are plenty of addon's and other methods that might work better for your particular habits and tastes but this method is native to Chrome w/o additional downloads.